# UILocalNotification not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to make a chat app in which, when you are in a conversation with another person and receive a message from another one you display a local notification.

This far I implemented this in my view:

```
else {
    // in case the user that sent the message 
    // is not the same as the one you are currently talking to
    var partOfIt = msg.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")[1].componentsSeparatedByString(":")[6] as NSString
    var tuple = (partOfIt,fromuser)
    println("open up a new view")
    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    let dateTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2)
    notification.fireDate = dateTime
    notification.alertBody = "Woww it works!!"
    notification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens except for the `println`. I have allowed notifications to be shown when I use my app.

Furthermore, I also want to open a new view. when the user clicks this notification, how do I do this?

Is it something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notifications show up only when your app is in background. Even local ones.
Since you send the notification in 2 seconds, I guess your app is still open.

By the way you should still be able to see the notification in the notification center (even if you didn't have any "popup bar").

Comment: and is there a way to enable the pop up bar?

Comment: Nope, you need to create one yourself (so it won't be the system one), I wen't in the same problem not long ago. It's a bit boring ^^'

Answer (score 7):

1. the fireDate must be future time.
2. app must be running in backdrop, or is closed.
3. one more thing, do not forget to show query whether to allow push, add below code to appDelegate:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
         UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
         [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Local notifications are handled in `AppDelegate`. If your app is running, you have to implement `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`, if not - you should handle it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (local notification is found at `UILocalNotificationKey` or something like that).